# Calling a shell script from python

Tags: python, shell

I have a python script that calls a shell scrips, that in turn calls a .exe called iv4_console. I need to print the stdout of iv4_console for debugging purposes. I used this:
Python:

```
import sys
import subprocess

var="rW015005000000"
proc = subprocess.Popen(["c.sh", var], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output = ''
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ""):
        print line
        output += line
```

Shell:

```
start_dir=$PWD
release=$1
echo Release inside shell: $release
echo Directory: $start_dir
cd $start_dir
cd ../../iv_system4/ports/visualC12/Debug
echo Debug dir: $PWD
./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua ../../../../../logs/$release/VASP_DUN722_20160307_Krk_Krk_113048_092_1_$release.dvl &>../../../../FCW/ObjectDetectionTest/VASP_DUN722_20160307_Krk_Krk_113048_092_1_$release.xml
./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua ../../../../../logs/$release/VASP_FL140_20170104_C60_Checkout_afterIC_162557_001_$release.dvl &>../../../../FCW/ObjectDetectionTest/VASP_FL140_20170104_C60_Checkout_afterIC_162557_001_$release.xml

exit
```

But this didn't work, it prints nothing. What do you think?

Comment: Your Python code won't run. Please show the actual code.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the quotes around `rW015005000000`

Comment: What is `proc`, then?

Comment: Have you tried `proc = subprocess.Popen(["c.sh", var])`?

Comment: Don'r work either

Comment: Question: do you really need the shell script? Seems way easier just coding it into your python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment, best approach (i.m.o) would be to just use python only.

However, in answer of your question, try:

```
import sys
import subprocess

var="rW015005000000"
proc = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "/full/path/to/c.sh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
# Best to always avoid shell=True because of security vulnerabilities. 
proc.wait() # To make sure the shell script does not continue running indefinitely in the background 
output, errors = proc.communicate()

print(output.decode()) 
# Since subprocess.communicate() returns a bytes-string, you can use .decode() to print the actual output as a string.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./c.sh'])
```

to call the shell script in python file

or

```
import subprocess
import shlex

subprocess.call(shlex.split('./c.sh var'))
```

Comment: I couldn't print the stdout using `subprocess.call`. And using `shlex` didn't work.

Comment: try with 
import os
os.system('sh c.sh')